# Options for using Spring, Hibernate, JPA, and Tomcat with multiple Databases

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat, jpa, jta

I have a java web app running under Spring 2.5.6, Hibernate 3.4 (with Hibernate as the JPA provider), and Tomcat 6. I have it working with one DB schema / persistence unit but now need to connect to 2 schemas / persistence units. Can I do this without moving to a J2EE container such as JBoss or Glassfish? Will I need to use something like JOTM and global / XA transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to access multiple transactional resources within the same transaction, you'll need JTA and thus a JTA transaction manager. At the Spring level, this will mean using a [`JtaTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) instead of your [`JpaTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html). And if you don't want to move to a real Java EE app server, you'll have indeed to use a standalone transaction manager such as JOTM or Atomikos. I prefer the later but, personally, I would just move to GlassFish.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Tomcat with spring/hibernate, then use JBoss's Transaction Manager to create JTA transaction manager bean.

Here is a short tutorial http://ingenious-camel.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-use-jboss-transactions-in-spring.html